# jquery -> finding elements and navigating throug?

Tags: jquery, find

i wonder how i can solve the following problem.

i have a horizontal scrollbar with floating divs side by side (.picture_holder). I wonder if i can find() this elements and animate a scroll event to the startpoint of every image. If i reach the last div i it to scroll to the first.

```
#
$('.next').click(function(){
#
$('html, body').animate({scrollTo:Position von .picture_holder2}, 'slow');
#
});
```

?? any ideas how i could solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scroll horizontally to a position using jQuery's `.scrollLeft()` function.

http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/

If you want it animated, do this:

**Live Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/b5Xps/

```
$('.next').click(function(){

      // Get left offset position of the target
    var leftPosition = $('.picture_holder2').offset().left;

      // animate the scrollLeft property to that position
    $('html,body').animate({scrollLeft: leftPosition }, 1000);​

});
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution? Don't reinvent the [scrollable](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/).